# Using zIndex for webGL

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have three.js program, now

What I want to do is

- Showing the 2D panel (for debug parameter shown purpose) on three.js.

So my idea is making `div` and show this in front of three.js using z-index.

However my 2D panel is not shown.

My quesiton is.

My idea using div and showing this in front of webGL is correct ? or should I make the panel in webGL?

These are my source code

```
import React,{useRef,useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';

import styles from "../css/test-styles.module.css";

import * as THREE from 'three';
import TrackballControls from 'three-trackballcontrols';
import three_test from "../images/three_test.jpg";


function ThreeDebugInfo(){
    return <div style={{width:"500px",zIndex:100}}>testtesttest</div>
}

function GlCanvas() {
    const refContainer = useRef(null);
    useEffect(() => {
      // === THREE.JS CODE START ===
      var scene = new THREE.Scene();
      var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
  
      var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth /100 * 80, window.innerHeight / 100 * 80);
      // document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
      // use ref as a mount point of the Three.js scene instead of the document.body
      refContainer.current && refContainer.current.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
  
      camera.position.z = -500;
     
      const loadTex = async () =>{
          const texLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
     
          var  texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(three_test);
          console.log("check texture is loaded:",texture);
          var ground_geo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 3309, 2339, 8, 8 );
          ground_geo.translate(0, 0, -50);
          var ground_mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture });

          var ground = new THREE.Mesh(
              ground_geo,
              ground_mat
          );
          //ground.rotation.x = Math.PI / -2;
          
          scene.add( ground );
  
          var cube_geo = new THREE.BoxGeometry(100, 100, 100);
          //cube_geo.translate(25, 0, 25);
          var cube_mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
          var cube = new THREE.Mesh(cube_geo, cube_mat);
          scene.add(cube);
         
          

          const controls = new TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
       
          camera.position.z = 5;
          controls.rotateSpeed = 5.0; //回転速度
          controls.zoomSpeed = 1.2;
          controls.panSpeed = 0.3;
          controls.update();
           
          const animate = function () {

            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
           
            // Required for updating during animations.
            controls.update();
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
          }
          animate();
      
  
      }
      loadTex();
  
    
    }, []);
    return (
        
        <div style={{zIndex:1}} ref={refContainer}></div>
   
    );
}

function ThreePage() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
        <GlCanvas></GlCanvas>
        <ThreeDebugInfo></ThreeDebugInfo>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

export default ThreePage
```

Answer (score 0):

The z-index value has no effect. To make it work, set the css `position` to another value than `static` on the element with the `z-index` (zIndex)

> **position: static**
>
> The element is positioned according to the normal flow of the document. The `top`, `right`, `bottom`, `left`, and `z-index` properties have no effect.
>
> This is the default value.

*Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#static*